# Disable FIPS with command line

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, cmd, fips

How can i disable the FIPS with the command line?
Is there a way?
Or can you tell me with which tool i have to configurate it?

would really be thankfull for a little help.

I want to include it in a C# project.

[image]

*here a view of the configuration i want to change*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a C# Project you can add a Configuration File (App.config) to disable the FIPS.

insert this code:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```